# Setting a custom Id to a NSWindow

Tags: macos, nswindow

I am creating a multi-window application on macOS. Each window created by me is a NSWindow. I would like to assign a custom Id as per my need, to the created NSWindow so that I can later find the window using the Id. Is there a way to do it ?

I understand there is a property called windowNumber. However, one cannot set this to a value as they desire.

> `var windowNumber: Int { get }`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `NSWindow` conforms to `NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification`. It has a settable [`identifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsuserinterfaceitemidentification/1396829-identifier) property (a `String`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `identifier` property of a `NSWindow` object to assign a custom id string to a window, like this:

```
let myWindowIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("My window identifier")

window.identifier = myWindowIdentifier
```

To find a window using this identifier, you use code like this:

```
for window in NSApp.windows {
    if window.identifier == myWindowIdentifier {
        // Do something
        break
    }
}
```